# How to make jQuery to continously request the same HTTP GET request

Tags: jquery, ajax, comet, real-time

I am implementing a software that reads system status with jQuery by using **$.getJSON**.

The idea is that I am displaying real-time data in browser and want to update the data as often as possible. The server is also running on localhost so theoretically I should be able to get very low latency (at least < 50 ms, even less than 20).

But question is this: how can I implement getJSON with jQuery so that the HTTP GET request will be automatically resend straight after the earlier request was finished?

In my current implementation I have defined an update function:

```
function updateSimulation() {       
   $.getJSON('/simulation/', function(data) {
      // ..parse data here
   });    
}
```

And added a callback once every 50 ms:

```
document.simulationIntervalId = setInterval( "updateSimulation()", 50 );
```

The problem is that if a request takes longer than 50 ms, several requests will be waiting for a result asynchronously, meaning that if one request takes longer, older data maybe replaced with newer data, which is not desirable.

So basically it means one of the following two solutions could be consider: 1) either when a response arrives, all pending requests could be killed (not optimal), 2) a new request is only sent after the previous one has returned (perhaps optimal solution).

But as always, all comments and answers are much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you to all answerers so far, you have been not only very helpful, but also very quick! I will need to do some testing with the given solutions, and I will come back with my answer, once I found the best possible solution. THANK YOU ALL AND HAPPY CHRISTMAS! Based on this question alone I would say you people at Stackoverflow.com ROCK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you call updateSimulation on the success function (the second parameter of $.getJSON) ?

It will do the request after the previous one has finished.

Comment: Let's say that.... I feel like an idiot :9 This is totally the way to go, thanks!

Comment: When you are so deeply thinking about how to implement something, you not always think about the simplest solution :)

Comment: I would suggest not to take this direction. You'll overload your processor: **1.** You'll put a heavy load on your processor and **2.** You'll get into a huge stack state, because you'll be nesting calls. **Don't directly call it within itself.**

Comment: The problem is more located on the initial idea of executing a request "continuously", maybe trying to reduce the requests by executing a setInterval on a 5s period ?

Comment: But I didn't knew all the implication of calling multiple times a function within itself. Do you have any informations (links?) about it @Robert Koritnik ? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this answer alone doesn't solve the problem, but its the right step towards the right way (=not executing several calls in parallel, but rather serially). Some timeout may need need to be added not to overload the system, but really, at this moment I'm just trying to optimise latency.

Comment: Robert: can you elaborate? I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, when using `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, don't pass the method in as a string, as this calls the infamous `eval()` which is poor coding practice. Rather pass the method like this: `setInterval(updateSimulation, 50);`

To make sure the ajax request has completed before another one is sent off, use `setTimeout()` to only call the `updateSimulation()` method once, and then on the jquery's ajax success event, call `updateSimulation()` again.

Answer (score 1):

### Parse and use data first, then issue a deferred call

Use `window.setTimeout()` instead and reissue another one after you've done processing the current one. This way there will be no *overlapping*.

```
function updateSimulation() {
   $.getJSON('/simulation/', function(data) {
      // ..parse data here
      window.setTimeout(updateSimulation, 250);
   });
}
```

Adjust timing as you wish...

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout instead, and call it on return of precedent call. It will run 50 ms after return (btw, 50 ms is far too small for AJAX, think about 500 ms or 1000 )

You can also add timestamp to sent data,  and compare it against last known timeout

```
function updateSimulation() {               
   $.getJSON('/simulation/', function(data) {
         window.setTimeout(updateSimulation, 500 );

         if (data.sent > last_data_sent){
           // use data
           last_data_sent = data.sent

         }

   });              
}
```

Comment: this may overlap as well... *using data* code part is the one that takes an arbitrary amount of time (depending on browser, javascript engine and other factors... This isn't right.

Comment: Yes thank you for the tips, but please notice that I am really trying to achieve latency lower than 50 ms so this isn't an ordinary Ajax scenario.

Comment: you can just place window.setTimeout(updateSimulation, latency_ms ); at the end of processing data. Thus latency will be (latency_ms + time of data processing). But in the real-world, if you are doing things over http, it will be really hard to assume 50 ms (hint: look at autocompletion speed at google search page, which is quite optimised  in terms of both code and infrastructure)

Answer (score 1):

You also could use the setInterval with the period you want (50ms for example) and add an indicator to know if the previous request has finished.
This indicator doesn't have to be in the gobal array thought.

```
function updateSimulation() {
   if (!requesting) {
      requesting = true;
      $.getJSON('/simulation/', function(data) {
         requesting = false;
      });
   }
}

var requesting = false;
setInterval ('updateSimulation', 50);
```

Where namespace is an object you use.

Answer (score 0):

2) sounds good, but 50ms is a little bit quick. I don't think that the Server will like it.

Comment: It probably doesn't make any sense to users either.

Comment: Of course it makes sense, why do you think people optimize webpages, use CDNs, CSS-sprites and other techniques?  Improve performance(what makes sense to the user) or from boredom? 50ms means 20 request in a second, 1200 in a minute->the server has a lot to do with it and less capacity for other requests.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Yes they do optimize things. But doing requests every 50ms doesn't make much sense. Even if you'd be doing a chat web application it wouldn't make any obvious difference whether it was 50 or 250 or maybe even 500 ms. Chat would be smooth either way. But would put much less load on the server if it was 500ms... As well as on the client, because there would be much less processing involved.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: All those optimisations you mentioned are related to network lag... And issuing frequent requests doesn't really help. We'd need some more information of the end application process to see benefit in such short intervals.

Comment: I get your point, but really, I am implementing a real-time application. And with real-time, I really mean real-time: my goal is to achieve decent fps (frames per second) for a visualisation that uses the data from the request. A decent being fps > 20, which means 50 ms is the minimum latency. In other use cases such as chat, it really wouldn't matter if its 100 ms or 50 ms, but in my work it counts. I know its experimental, but that's why I work on research.

Comment: I'm afraid you will not get a response every 50ms, no matter which interval you use(you could be happy if you get it every 500ms). Maybe AJAX is not a good choice for your application.

Comment: If you really need real-real time, consider using WebSockets.

Comment: Actually the reason I have to do this hack is that we are currently not able to use web sockets. And I agree: in the long run, web sockets are totally the way to go!